# How to convert hms time format to plain string wth ms (minute:second) format

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- structure(list(cuml = structure(c(109200, 214980, 325560), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It looks like this:

```
> dat
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  cuml  
  <time>
1 30:20 
2 59:43 
3 90:26
```

Not they are in minute:second format. What I want to do is to print them like this:

```
(30:20)
(59:43)
(90:26)
```

But when I do this,

```
   dat %>%
      mutate(cuml = paste0("(", format(cuml, "%s"),")"))
```

I get this, which is not exactly what I want:

```
(30:20:00)
(59:43:00)
(90:26:00)
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
dat$cuml <-  paste0("(", substr(dat$cuml, 1, 5), ")")
```

Answer (score 1):

Although we don't see them in the tibble format but `dat$cuml` has 3 components in them.

```
dat$cuml

#30:20:00
#59:43:00
#90:26:00
```

We can use regex to extract the first two :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(cuml = sprintf('(%s)', sub('(\\d+:\\d+).*', '\\1', cuml)))

#   cuml   
#  <chr>  
#1 (30:20)
#2 (59:43)
#3 (90:26)
```

Comment: I find it weird that scamander doesn't see the 3 components in the tibble. R studio does display them for me. Doesn't it makes sense it has 3 components as the structure is specified to be hms (or in other words, hours, minutes, seconds)?

Comment: Yes, I think those are `hms`.